# understanding two regexp used to read tsv file

Tags: regex, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am reading in a tsv file with regex I found somewhere, but I dont really understand them :)

They are:

```
(..*)
```

for the entire document and

```
([^\t][^\t]*)\t?|\t
```

for the values. I played around in regexpal and what I dont get is, why I cant use

```
(.*)
```

and

```
([^\t]*)\t?
```

instead.

At least I get an error in my xslt analyze-string when I use them (error: zero-length string).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `(.*)` instead of `(..*)` because your new expression matches empty strings, while the original requires at least one character to be there. You could, however, use `(.+)`, which is an equivalent of `(..*)` expression.

Same goes for the second expression: you can rewrite it using `+` like this:

```
([^\t]+)\t?|\t
```

It looks like the original expression is missing parentheses around the first OR-ed subexpression:

```
(([^\t]+)\t?)|\t
```

otherwise, `|` applies to `\t?`, making it "an optional tab or a tab", which hardly makes sense.

Comment: It should probably be noted that your second example (`(?:([^\t]+)\t?)|\t`) is only valid in XSLT 3.0. It will throw an [error](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#err-XTDE1140) (non-capturing group) in XSLT 2.0.

Comment: @DanielHaley You're right, the question is specifically tagged for XSLT 2.0. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

You could shorten `(..*)` to `(.+)` as those match one or more characters. With the same approach you can shorten `[^\t][^\t]*` in your second expression to `[^\t]+` as that would match one or more non-tab characters.